# java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/ec2-user/src/main/resources/keystore.jks (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, spring-boot, resources

I am having a problem referencing a file within my jar file specifically the keystore.jks. I stored the file inside the resources file but it seems when i try to run the springboot project the file isnt picked up.

I get this error :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/ec2-user/src/main/resources/keystore.jks (No such file or directory)
```

This is my applications.properties file :

```
server.ssl.key-store=src/main/resources/keystore.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=mypassword
server.ssl.keyStoreType=JKS
server.ssl.keyAlias=my_alias
```

This is my project structure :

[image]

Comment: Please show the java code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use:

```
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.jks
```

Documentation: [docs.spring.io](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-resourceloader).

Answer (score 1):

To read from the resource file:

applications.properties

```
server.ssl.key-store=keystore.jks
```

java

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(prop.getProperty("server.ssl.key-store")).getFile());
```

Comment: Where do i add this login within my spring boot project?

Answer (score 0):

Your application seems starting in `/home/ec2-user/`.
You should set `server.ssl.key-store`path relative to `/home/ec2-user/`

Comment: OP Is embedding the JKS inside of the jar, the relativity of the filepath doesn't matter, as the actual JKS file isn't **on** the filesystem as a standalone file

Comment: The keystore.jks file is within the jar file im not sure if following your approach would work

Answer (score 0):

I have  had same  problem. My Solution  is

my applications.properties file :

```
jvm:
    key-store-type: PKCS12
    key-store: banking.p12
    key-store-password: aWRldmh1YlU=
```

[This is my project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSTEJ.png)

And my key store loader

```
public InputStream getKeyStoreStream(String resourceName) {
    ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    return loader.getResourceAsStream(resourceName);
}
```

And load

```
    @Value("${jvm.trust-store}")
    private String JVM_TRUST_STORE;

    @Value("${jvm.key-store}")
    private String JVM_KEY_STORE;

keysP12 = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
keysP12.load(getKeyStoreStream(JVM_KEY_STORE), keyStorePassword);
```

I think for JKS same  way

```
keysJks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
keysJks.load(getKeyStoreStream(JVM_TRUST_STORE), trustStorePassword);
```

Comment: So you created a seperate class to handle the keystore.jks file ?

Comment: I have created only method getKeyStoreStream for load keystore.jks. This method is part of Class for TLS connection. Param resourceName  it  is file name for example keystore.jks. I get thes name from properties file